# Where is the documentation for Adobe XFL Flash interchange format?

Tags: xml, flash, adobe, flash-cs4

I work at an animation studio that does several productions in Flash.  Probably one of the most exciting features of the new Adobe CS4 suite is the XFL file format.  At last, I have an ascii format that I can use to tighten our Flash-to-After Effects pipeline, as well as scene plan entire episodes without ever having to have Flash open.

My only problem is that I can't find the official documentation on the Adobe website anywhere.  I've tried searching the Adobe site itself but only came up with guides on how to export XFL from various CS4 apps.  Google searches yielded similar results, with nothing pointing to the official specification.

I'm interested in building a Python API so that I can generate XLF from my pipeline scripts natively, but can't do so until I know all the aspects of the format.

Comment: For the record, some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077200/whats-the-meaning-of-the-non-numerical-values-in-the-xfls-edge-definition

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get your FLA files to open in AFX. It clearly goes the other way, but that's the opposite direction I need it to go in as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Richard Galvan, the Flash authoring product manager at Adobe, they have not publicly released the documentation yet. The following quote is from [moockblog](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000269.html)'s interview with Richard back in March '08:

> "The exact details of the XFL format are not yet available, but Richard assures me that Adobe intends to document them publicly, allowing third-party tools to import and export XFL."

The problem with moving to an open format like XFL is that people are less likely to pay for Adobe's proprietary IDE when they can use a cheaper (maybe even open source) 3rd party alternative just as easily. Maybe they're trying to cook up a cunning way of ensuring that they keep us locked in.

Comment: The Link says: "The exact details of the XFL format are not yet available, but Richard assures me that Adobe intends to document them publicly, allowing third-party tools to import and export XFL." This clearly is the answer.

Comment: I'd disagree with the open format since most people use Flash because they like the IDE.  The same holds true for Maya, Shake, etc.  They all have open formats and the only people who care are studios building pipelines.

Comment: Joe, I've edited my answer to include the linked text exactly as shown

Comment: Soviut, I see where you're coming from, I just couldn't think of a good reason for Adobe to not put it out there - I can't believe that it doesn't exist in some form or another!